# The last two digits of $217^{382}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am currently solving this problem but it's getting out of my head so I want to ask your help in order to resolve it.

Find the last two digits of $217^{382}$

I'm supposed to use Euler's theorem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: consider $$217^ {382} \mod 100$$

Comment: It is pretty obvious that $217^{382}\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, hence you just have to find $217^{382}\equiv 17^2\pmod{25}$ and invoke the Chinese remainder theorem. It turns out that the last two digits are $89$, and there already are plenty of similar questions on MSE.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you should look up [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), which generalizes Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler's Theorem says that $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$. Since $100=2^2\cdot 5^2$, we have $\phi(100)=(4-2)(25-5)=40$. Now

\begin{align}
217^{382}&\equiv 17^{382}\\
&\equiv (17^{40})^9(17^{22})\\
&\equiv 17^{22}\pmod {100}
\end{align}

Now $17^2=289\equiv 89 \pmod {100}$, so we have

\begin{align}
217^{382}&\equiv 89^{11}\\
&\equiv 89^5\cdot 89^5\cdot 89\\
&\equiv 49\cdot 49\cdot 89\\
&\equiv 89.
\end{align}

I'll leave it to you to find a snappier way to end it if you want, but the problem becomes fairly manageable once you get to the second half.

Comment: It took me a while but I think now upon seeing this solution in detailed view, I think I understand how it works. Thank you so much! :)